# Supabase with Android Studio Java

Tags: java, supabase

Is there a away to use services provided by Supabase in android studio with Java and not with Kotlin?
and if there is, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Supabase services in an Android Studio project with Java. Supabase provides a REST API that you can interact with using HTTP requests, and you can use any programming language that supports HTTP requests to communicate with Supabase services.
You can use libraries like HttpURLConnection, OkHttp, or Apache HttpClient to make HTTP requests

Comment: can you provide some links to examples on how to do this please?